# nginx + angular 9 error in production for mobile browsers

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, production-environment, angular9

I'm facing an error in production and I can't figure out the reason of it.

The website I'm working on is a new project http://basefounder.com.

I made a service to collect a mailing list for people who want to get updates of it.

When I use the website in development I can do it without any problems, but when I try to do it from production, I get the following error.

```
{
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  },
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "Unknown Error",
  "url": "http://localhost:4040/api/user/email",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:4040/api/user/email: 0 Unknown Error",
  "error": {
    "isTrusted": true
  }
}
```

To help debugging in production envirornment, I added the error received from Node server in the FE page, right under the join mailing list button.

Hope someone has any ideas, if you need more info ask me and I'll provide it.

Thank you
Domenico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are making the HTTP request to a development back-end URL from the production front-end. I received the same error when trying to add an email from my desktop browser (Firefox)

[image]

Check if you've configured the URL correctly in the Angular application.

Also it's an OPTIONS request, which most probably mean it's a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) due to CORS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my node server runs on the same machine of the my angular app, that&#39;s why it calls localhost on that port. I don&#39;t understand the reason of this problem and why i don&#39;t receive this error from my laptop

Comment: Because probably you are running the node server in the same machine. So it's available only that in the machine at the moment.

Comment: @DomenicoVitoScalera `localhost` corresponds to the machine or device your are displaying the page from.  You need to replace it with some domain name available to people

Comment: @MichaelD and David thank you for your comments. If I understand well what you are saying,  I should call 'http://basefounder:4040/api/user/email' instead of 'http://localhost:4040/api/user/email'? At the moment, I redirect with nginx the traffic from port 80 to my angular application, giving the localhost and port of the angular application. In this case, since both angular application and node server run on the same machine (clearly with two different ports), why i should expose the server and can't just refer to my server giving [link](localhost:4040)?

Comment: Anyway your answer helped me understand better the problem (the reason why it was working on my laptop it was because I had the node server running in background).

Comment: The call I make from Angular is really simple `inserEmailMailingList(email: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:4040/api/user/email', {email: email});
  }`  As @MichaelD said, it becomes a preflight request,